# Unable to activate GNOME screen sharing

Tags: gnome, vnc, manjaro

As the title says I'm unable to activate screen sharing over the settings menu. The button it there but I am unable to toggle it, it just does not respond.
A had screen sharing running and working on the same machine about three weeks ago without any issues.

Do you have any ideas how I can make it activate-able again? (If you need any additional information, I will be happy to provide them.)

I'm on `GNOME 3.36.0` using `X11` and I've installed vnc via `pacman -S vino` from `extra/vino`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered a solution on the Manjaro forum. Since Upstream considers `vino` deprecated in of favour of `gnome-remote-desktop`, I had to install `gnome-remote-desktop`instead.

To enable `gnome-remote-desktop` I did the following:

```
Uninstall vino
Verify that gnome-remote-desktop is installed
Modify /etc/gdm/custom.conf and put WaylandEnable=true in the [daemon] section
Reboot
Enable screen sharing again.
```

Source:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/gnome-screen-sharing-breaks-in-3-36/131586/11